# ParseTree will not work with ruby 1.9. Why?

Tags: ruby

As per [this](http://blog.zenspider.com/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html) parsetree will not work in ruby 1.9 . I do not have computer science background but have been programming for a few years. Can someone explain in a little extra detail why parsetree will not work in ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 3):

The ruby 1.8 interpreter constructed and then walked over an abstract syntax tree, whereas the ruby 1.9 interpreter is bytecode based. Therefore there is no AST available at runtime for parsetree to work with.

Answer (score 3):

ngty has published a gem, called sourcify, that provides a lot of ParseTree's functionality in Ruby 1.9.

Since he couldn't use the AST, he wrote an sexp parser that works most of the time. Sometimes you have to give it some help, for example by telling it which Proc the code is attached to:

```
## The old ParseTree way
# proc.to_ruby
## The sourcify way - but may raise NoMatchingProcError or MultipleMatchingProcsPerLineError
# proc.to_source
## The sourcify way - giving :attached_to a symbol to help it find the correct Proc
proc.to_source :attached_to => :name_of_proc
```

Here's a longer explanation of [how we replaced ParseTree when we migrated to Ruby 1.9](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2010/12/17/replacing-parsetree-in-ruby-1-9).

Answer (score 2):

ParseTree appears to be dead due to some changes internally to Ruby 1.9, as per this link:
http://blog.zenspider.com/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html

Though, it may be that some people will come up with some workarounds for part of it.